# Sum third value in tuple for a given pair of the first two values in the tuple using Python

Tags: python, tuples

the question I have is related to the "Sum second value in tuple for each given first value in tuples using Python" and the "How do I sum the first value in each tuple in a list of tuples in Python?" topic, but I was not able to extract the solution for my problem from them.
I want to sum the third entry for each tuple, that contains the same pattern in the first and second entry of the tuple.
Lets say, there is an array containing integers, describing bin-positions for an x-Axis. Additionally, there is an array containing integers, describing the bin-number for an y-axis. The third array contains the corresponding "weigths".

Assume that

```
    ix = [0,1,2,0,1] and 
    iy = [0,1,1,0,1] and 
    w = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

With "zip" I created tuples from those arrays, leading to:

```
    [0,0,1]
    [1,1,2]
    [2,1,3]
    [0,0,4]
    [1,1,5]
```

As described above, I want so sum the third entry of all tuples, if the first two entries are the same, in this case "describing the same position in an 2D-space"
Therefore, the output should be the following three n-tuples:

```
    [0,0,5]
    [1,1,7]
    [2,1,3]
```

How can this be realized?
Thank you and best regards, Marc

Comment: You can use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Counter`s are meant for this (mostly); they make counting simple:

```
from collections import Counter

ix = [0,1,2,0,1]
iy = [0,1,1,0,1]
w = [1,2,3,4,5]

counts = Counter()
for (key, count) in zip(zip(ix, iy), w):
    counts[key] += count
print "Counts:", counts

counts_as_list = [  # Conversion of the counting result (counts) to a list
    [key[0], key[1], total_count] for (key, total_count) in counts.iteritems()]    
print "As a list:", counts_as_list
```

gives

```
Counts: Counter({(1, 1): 7, (0, 0): 5, (2, 1): 3})
As a list: [[0, 0, 5], [1, 1, 7], [2, 1, 3]]
```

**PS**: ferhat elmas's solution with a `collections.defaultdict(int)` is good too. However, using a `Counter` like above has the advantage of making it explicit that you are counting things—and of using a standard class intended to do just this. Furthermore, in general, you may end up using the special capabilities of counters. For all these reasons, I do recommend using `Counter` over a `defaultdict(int)` (even if it is some kind of not-so-poor-man's `Counter`).

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict` nicely does what you need:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> res = defaultdict(int)
>>> for p in zip(w, *[ix, iy]):
        res[p[1:]] += p[0]
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(0, 0): 5, (1, 1): 7, (2, 1): 3})
```

Comment: This fails on the example in the question (the count for (0, 0) is incorrect): when you create the dictionary, only a single valu `(x, y)` is kept.

Comment: @EOL missed that. thanks for pointing. updated my solution to work as expected.

Comment: This is good, now. That said, I would recommend using a `Counter()` instead of a `defaultdict`, because this makes it explicit that we are counting, and because it is easy to combine counters, if need be. But then this is my solution, so there is no need to change yours. :)

Comment: @EOL I agree but you had already written your answer so I tried to provide a bit different answer with `defaultdict`.

Comment: I quoted your answer in mine, because it's a fine one.

Answer (score -1):

Iterating through array and comparing 1st and 2nd value, if equals then add.

Also mark the ones that have been already used.

[@EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42973/eol) Thanks for comment.

```
arrays = [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [0, 0, 4], [1, 1, 5]]
new = []

for i,a in enumerate(arrays):
    for j,b in enumerate(arrays[i+1:]):
        if a[0] == b[0] and a[1] == b[1]:
            #print a,b,(a[2] + b[2])
            a.append('added')
            b.append('added')
            new.append([a[0],a[1],a[2] + b[2]])
    if 'added' not in a:
        new.append(a)

print new
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 5], [1, 1, 7], [2, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: This is not what the question asks for: for example, the count of 3 for for [2, 1, 3] must be counted.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Now, this is very, very complicated, and asymptotically slow. You can have a look at the `defaultdict(int)` and `Counter` solutions. The slow test that you are doing (`if … == … and … == …) is automatically done (in constant time) by dictionaries or collection.Counters. Essentially, by using the structures provided by Python, you can make your code much shorter, legible, and fast.

Comment: Oh yeah, once I saw other solutions I knew that there are way better ways to do it. I just wanted to make sure that mine is working correctly. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: That's the spirit. :)